# Fast nonzero indices per row/column for (sparse) 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am looking for the fastest way to obtain a list of the nonzero indices of a 2D array per row and per column. The following is a working piece of code:

```
preds = [matrix[:,v].nonzero()[0] for v in range(matrix.shape[1])]
descs = [matrix[v].nonzero()[0] for v in range(matrix.shape[0])]
```

**Example input:**

```
matrix = np.array([[0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,0]])
```

**Example output**

```
preds = [array([1, 2, 3]), array([2, 3]), array([3]), array([], dtype=int64)]
descs = [array([], dtype=int64), array([0]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 1, 2])]
```

(The lists are called preds and descs because they refer to the predecessors and descendants in a DAG when the matrix is interpreted as an adjacency matrix but this is not essential to the question.)

**Timing example:**
For timing purposes, the following matrix is a good representative:

```
test_matrix = np.zeros(shape=(4096,4096),dtype=np.float32)
for k in range(16):
    test_matrix[256*(k+1):256*(k+2),256*k:256*(k+1)]=1
```

**Background:** In my code, these two lines take 75% of the time for a 4000x4000 matrix whereas the ensuing topological sort and DP algorithm take only the rest of the quarter. Roughly 5% of the values in the matrix are nonzero so a sparse-matrix solution may be applicable.

Thank you.

(On suggestion posted here as well: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/35242/fast-nonzero-indices-per-row-column-for-sparse-2d-numpy-array
There are also answers there to which I will provide timings in the comments. **This link contains an accepted answer that is twice as fast.**)

Comment: I recommend you asking this on https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ there is a better place

Comment: @eusoubrasileiro Okay I will ask the question there. Should I then also remove it here or post a link to it?

Comment: @CJR I am looking for a very fast way to do so since this is a part of my code that is very limiting while I feel it should be done more quickly. As for you suggestion, perhaps I misunderstand but I don't think it does exactly the same thing? Will the sum not make a value True along an axis so long as there is at least one True in that row/column?

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal example](/help/mcve) including *toy* input/output?

Comment: @CJR I should mention that simply constructing the CSR matrix im my code already seems to take about as much time as the aforementioned two lines. I should clarify that I have got working code but it feels like it should be possible to be more efficient than repeatedly calling this `nonzero()` function. However, since the number of indices returned by this row/column can vary, I cannot simply extract this information from calling `nonzero()` once on the full matrix.

Comment: @norok2 Yes you are right. I added it.

Comment: Do you also have some indication of the input sizes, the typical sparsity coefficient and perhaps any assumption on the input (for example, your toy input is low triangular)?

Comment: @norok2 I added a timing example matrix which is representative of my actual matrix.

Comment: @eusoubrasileiro, why did you recommend the `scicomp` board?  This looks like Python/numpy programming question, not a theoretical one.  Are you active on that board, and prepared to answer this question there?

Comment: @hpaulj I think there is onverlap in some aspects but there is normally best suited for this kind of questions https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic from my experience, just trying to help the guy to have an answer

Comment: @eusoubrasileiro, I see he got a useful answer on `scicomp`.  I haven't looked at that board before.  More often I object to referrals to `codereview`.  `numpy` questions on SO cover both debugging and enhancement ("vectorization") topics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have enough motivation, Numba can do amazing things.
Here is a quick implementation of the logic you need.
Briefly, it computes the equivalent of `np.nonzero()` but it includes along the way the information to later dispatch the indices into the format you require.
The information is inspired by `sparse.csr.indptr` and `sparse.csc.indptr`.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


@nb.jit
def cumsum(arr):
    result = np.empty_like(arr)
    cumsum = result[0] = arr[0]
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        cumsum += arr[i]
        result[i] = cumsum
    return result


@nb.jit
def count_nonzero(arr):
    arr = arr.ravel()
    n = 0
    for x in arr:
        if x != 0:
            n += 1
    return n


@nb.jit
def row_col_nonzero_nb(arr):
    n, m = arr.shape
    max_k = count_nonzero(arr)
    indices = np.empty((2, max_k), dtype=np.uint32)
    i_offset = np.zeros(n + 1, dtype=np.uint32)
    j_offset = np.zeros(m + 1, dtype=np.uint32)
    n, m = arr.shape
    k = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            if arr[i, j] != 0:
                indices[:, k] = i, j
                i_offset[i + 1] += 1
                j_offset[j + 1] += 1
                k += 1
    return indices, cumsum(i_offset), cumsum(j_offset)


def row_col_idx_nonzero_nb(arr):
    (ii, jj), jj_split, ii_split = row_col_nonzero_nb(arr)
    ii_ = np.argsort(jj)
    ii = ii[ii_]
    return np.split(ii, ii_split[1:-1]), np.split(jj, jj_split[1:-1])
```

Compared to your approach (`row_col_idx_sep()` below), and a bunch of others, as per [@hpaulj answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62069263/5218354) (`row_col_idx_sparse_lil()`) and [@knl answer from scicomp.stackexchange.com](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/35243/17871) (`row_col_idx_sparse_coo()`):

```
def row_col_idx_sep(arr):
    return (
        [arr[:, j].nonzero()[0] for j in range(arr.shape[1])],
        [arr[i, :].nonzero()[0] for i in range(arr.shape[0])],)
```

```
def row_col_idx_zip(arr):
    n, m = arr.shape
    ii = [[] for _ in range(n)]
    jj = [[] for _ in range(m)]
    x, y = np.nonzero(arr)
    for i, j in zip(x, y):
        ii[i].append(j)
        jj[j].append(i)
    return jj, ii
```

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.sparse


def row_col_idx_sparse_coo(arr):
    coo_mat = sp.sparse.coo_matrix(arr)
    csr_mat = coo_mat.tocsr()
    csc_mat = coo_mat.tocsc()
    return (
        np.split(csc_mat.indices, csc_mat.indptr)[1:-1],
        np.split(csr_mat.indices, csr_mat.indptr)[1:-1],)
```

```
def row_col_idx_sparse_lil(arr):
    lil_mat = sp.sparse.lil_matrix(arr)
    return lil_mat.T.rows, lil_mat.rows
```

For inputs generated using:

```
def gen_input(n, density=0.1, dtype=np.float32):
    arr = np.zeros(shape=(n, n), dtype=dtype)
    indices = tuple(np.random.randint(0, n, (2, int(n * n * density))).tolist())
    arr[indices] = 1.0
    return arr
```

One would get (your `test_matrix` had approximately 0.06 non-zero density):

```
m = gen_input(4096, density=0.06)
%timeit row_col_idx_sep(m)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 767 ms per loop
%timeit row_col_idx_zip(m)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 660 ms per loop
%timeit row_col_idx_sparse_coo(m)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 205 ms per loop
%timeit row_col_idx_sparse_lil(m)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 498 ms per loop
%timeit row_col_idx_nonzero_nb(m)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 130 ms per loop
```

Indicating this to be close to twice as fast as the fastest `scipy.sparse`-based approach.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive reply. Very useful!

Answer (score 1):

```
In [182]: arr = np.array([[0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,0]])
```

The data is present in the whole-array `nonzero`, just not broken up into per row/column arrays:

```
In [183]: np.nonzero(arr)                                                                
Out[183]: (array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]), array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2]))
In [184]: np.argwhere(arr)                                                               
Out[184]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 0],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 2]])
```

It might be possible to break the `array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])` into sublists, `[1,2,3],[2,3],[3],[]` based on the other array.  But it may take some time to work out the logic for that, and there's no guarantee that it will be faster than your row/column iterations.

Logical operations can reduce the boolean array to column or row, giving the rows or columns where nonzero occurs, but again not ragged:

```
In [185]: arr!=0                                                                         
Out[185]: 
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False]])
In [186]: (arr!=0).any(axis=0)                                                           
Out[186]: array([ True,  True,  True, False])
In [187]: np.nonzero((arr!=0).any(axis=0))                                               
Out[187]: (array([0, 1, 2]),)
In [188]: np.nonzero((arr!=0).any(axis=1))                                               
Out[188]: (array([1, 2, 3]),)
In [189]: arr                                                                            
Out[189]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

The `scipy.sparse` `lil` format does generate the data you want:

```
In [190]: sparse                                                                         
Out[190]: <module 'scipy.sparse' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/__init__.py'>
In [191]: M = sparse.lil_matrix(arr)                                                     
In [192]: M                                                                              
Out[192]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.longlong'>'
    with 6 stored elements in List of Lists format>
In [193]: M.rows                                                                         
Out[193]: array([list([]), list([0]), list([0, 1]), list([0, 1, 2])], dtype=object)
In [194]: M.T                                                                            
Out[194]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.longlong'>'
    with 6 stored elements in List of Lists format>
In [195]: M.T.rows                                                                       
Out[195]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([2, 3]), list([3]), list([])], dtype=object)
```

But timing probably isn't any better than your row or column iteration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To add some timings: for 10 runs on the 4096x4096 test_matrix this code runs about 1.5x slower than the original. However, for a matrix that is 100x larger than the one I provided, your code is about 20% faster. So depending on the matrix this is may be a good solution! Note also that a solution was provided on the other board but I don't know how to resolve the two different questions on the two boards.

Comment: @RichardSchoonhoven threat the two boards independently and this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers once you believe it's time

Comment: In my own testing, the list approach is better for small arrays.  The `csr` matrix approach does scale better (with arrays bigger than (1000,1000)).  My `lil` version is slower; timings suggest that `lil_matrix` first makes a `csr`, and then converts that to `lil`.  There's a lot going on under the covers in the `scipy.sparse` code, and creating a matrix from scratch can be time consuming.  A lot depends on the `sparsity` of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Its also possible to use `np.bincount()` for that, for example

```
# Suppose X is a sparse matrix
In [56]: X.shape
Out[56]: (5830, 93761)

# Non-zero elements per row
In [57]: np.bincount(X.nonzero()[0])
Out[57]: array([316, 305,  98, ..., 284, 915, 721])

# Non-zero elements per column
In [58]: np.bincount(X.nonzero()[1])
Out[58]: array([14, 10,  1, ...,  1,  1,  1])

# Its also reasonably quick
In [59]: %timeit np.bincount(X.nonzero()[0])
24.1 ms ± 393 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

One thing to watch out for is when there are rows/columns in your matrix that are all zeros:

```
In [60]: A = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]])
In [61]: np.bincount(A.nonzero()[0])
Out[61]: array([1]) # <-- Second row is all zeros, so its omitted here

In [62]: B = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
In [63]: np.bincount(B.nonzero()[0])
Out[63]: array([0, 1])
```